# Not sure how to accomplish this with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that I am running to eliminate duplicates over two semesters. Unfortunately I have to combine chpid, secno, lname, fname, and email to make the records unique for comparison.

The query provides a starting point for what I am trying to accomplish.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    '1' as Counter
    chpid,
    SECNO,
    LNAME,
    FNAME,
    EmailAddress
FROM 
    Eligmember
WHERE 
    ((FORMYEAR = 2018 AND FORMSEMESTER = 4) OR 
     (FORMYEAR = 2019 AND FORMSEMESTER = 2)) 
    AND presentmem <> 'Y'
```

Returns 58000 records

```
Counter chpid SECNO    LNAME     FNAME          EmailAddress
---------------------------------------------------------------
1       1     2        Banes     Moore          MMB@test.test
1       1     2        Baron     Lana           LRB@test.org
```

This is good to start with but what I want to do is count how many are in each chpid. I only need the counts for each person within each chpid but I have to select the chpid, secno, lname, fname, and email to make them unique.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY chpid)`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support `count(distinct)` with multiple expressions.  One method is a subquery:

```
SELECT chpid, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT chpid, SECNO, LNAME, FNAME, EmailAddress
      FROM Eligmember
      WHERE ((FORMYEAR = 2018 and FORMSEMESTER = 4) OR
             (FORMYEAR = 2019 and FORMSEMESTER = 2)
            ) and
            presentmem <> 'Y'
     ) c
GROUP BY chpid;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple GROUP BY scenario:

```
SELECT 
    Count(*) as Counter
    ,chpid
    ,max(SECNO) as SECNO
    ,LNAME
    ,FNAME
    ,max(EmailAddress) as EmailAddress
FROM 
    Eligmember
WHERE 
    ((FORMYEAR = 2018 AND FORMSEMESTER = 4) OR 
     (FORMYEAR = 2019 AND FORMSEMESTER = 2)) 
    AND presentmem <> 'Y'
GROUP BY 
    chpid
    ,LNAME  -- for each person within the chpid
    ,FNAME  -- ^
;
```

This "combine[s] chpid, secno, lname, fname, and email to make the records unique for comparison."  It also generates the desired result set.  This assumes that there is a 1:1  relationship between fname, lname and email address; if not then you need to remove the max and group by the email address.